# Django - Edição de tabelas (Update)

Tags: django, crud

Em minha aplicação eu tenho uma função buscar uma pessoa pelo nome e de editar dados de uma pessoa cadastrada...

Quando faço a busca e existe mais de uma pessoa cadastrada com aquele nome (ou mesmo quando tem apenas uma pessoa), os detalhes da busca são retornados em tabela deste modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde o campo de Codigo é a pk (Primary Key) dos objetos retornados. Na tabela no campo de Ação eu tenho o link para edição que direciona para seguinte view:

```
@login_required
def upPessoa(request, id):

    oPessoa = Pessoa.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormPessoa(request.POST, instance=oPessoa)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = FormPessoa(instance=oPessoa)

    return render(request,'template.html',
                {
                    'form':form,
                    'codigo':id,
                }
            )
```

minha url esta definida assim:

```
 url(r'^editar/usuario/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'library.views.upPessoa', name='nUpPessoa'),
```

Eu tenho 2 duvidas:

1- Como é que a url vai saber que o o objeto que eu quero editar é o de código x ou y ?! Mais especificamente como ela vai saber que o id a ser recebido na expressão `(?P<id>\d+)` e transmitido para a view é o 2 ou o 9 ?!

2 - Ao ser redirecionado para pagina de edição eu gostaria que os campos já viessem preenchidos com as informações cadastradas, eu verifiquei que tenho que usar um `initial` e passar ele como contexto na view so que não entendi muito bem como esse `initial` funciona.

Se precisar, meu projeto completo esta no [GitHub](https://github.com/Sniickers/Two)

Obs: As views e as urls ainda não estão como citado acima, pois ainda não fiz o commit das modificações.

Obs 2: Ainda sou iniciante no Django comecei a estudar a pouco tempo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1ª Questão

A url será tratada pelos middlewares do Django e ele então saberá qual é o Id porque você vai precisar passar isso apra a URL de seu campo `Ação` da tabela.
Exemplo

```
<td>
    <a href="/pesquisa/usuario/{{ codigo }}">Editar</a>
<td>
```

O que vai gerar como html, por exemplo:

```
<td>
    <a href="/pesquisa/usuario/2">Editar</a>
<td>
```

Sobre ***templates tags*** para a url, quando é necessário, é preciso inserir os parâmetros adicionais.
Exemplos:

```
{% url 'nUpPessoa' v1 v2 %}

{% url 'nUpPessoa' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}

{% url 'nUpPessoa' client.id %}
```

fonte: **[docs.djangoproject / templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)**

### 2ª Questão

Como você já está passando a referência do objeto para o formulário no caso do método `get`:

```
else:
    form = FormPessoa(instance=oPessoa)
```

Os valores então já deveriam aparecer nos campos caso você esteja criado o formulário dinâmicamente.
Exemplo da criação dinâmica:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Mas, caso esteja criando os campos/elementos manualmente, então pode passar o valor pelo form.
Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="login" name="login" 
    value="{{ form.login.value|default_if_none:"" }}" />
```

Dessas duas formas os valores não aparecerão caso o registro não tenha sido encontrado ou se ao criar os campos manualmente você informar nome de propriedade errado.

Caso não surja resposta mais ampla e que retire suas dúvidas, logo eu copio seu projeto e verifico como está.

Mais sobre como trabalhar com formulários em Django: **[Django Brasil - Forms](http://docs.djangobrasil.org/topics/forms/)**

Comment: A principio eu estava usando a template tag "{% url 'library.views.upPessoa' %}" no href do link Editar, para montar o caminho a apartir da view desejada. Então modifiquei para: href="editar/usuario/{{ pessoa.pk }}", e também precisei modificar minha RegEx da url para: r'^.+/editar/usuario/(?P<id>\d+)/$'. Mais uma pergunta: Teria algum modo de passar esse id para view de outra forma para não alterar a template tag ?! Agradeço a sua ajuda.